# Как получить связанные данные одним запросом?

Tags: laravel

Есть:

```
class YarnController extends Controller
{
    public function show($manufacturer, $collection = null)
    {
        if (!$collection) {
            $collections = Collection::whereHas('manufacturer', function($query) use ($manufacturer) {
                $query->where('id', $manufacturer);
            })->get();
        } else {
            $collections = Collection::whereHas('manufacturer', function($query) use ($manufacturer) {
                $query->where('id', $manufacturer);
            })->where('id', $collection)->get();
        }

        return view('yarn', compact('collections'));
    }
}
```

И

```
@foreach ($collections as $collection)
    <p>{{ $collection->manufacturer->name }} - {{ $collection->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Получается:

```
select * from `collections` where exists (select * from `manufacturers` where `collections`.`manufacturer_id` = `manufacturers`.`id` and `id` = '2')
select * from `manufacturers` where `manufacturers`.`id` = 2 limit 1
select * from `manufacturers` where `manufacturers`.`id` = 2 limit 1
select * from `manufacturers` where `manufacturers`.`id` = 2 limit 1
```

Коллекции производителя выводятся за один запрос, но вот для получения производителя каждый раз делается новый запрос.

Answer (score 0):

`whereHas` не загружает данные отношений, он только указывает какие данные должны быть получены. Используйте `with` для **EagerLoading**, что бы получить **manufacturers**.

```
Collection::with('manufacturer')->whereHas(
    'manufacturer',
    function($query) use ($manufacturer) {
            $query->where('id', $manufacturer);
        }
    )->where('id', $collection)->get();
```

Данный запрос вернет все **Collection** которые связаны с **manufacturer**, с `id` равным `$manufacturer`. А `with('manufacturer')` так же загрузит **все** `Manufactur` для каждой модели `Collection`.